# Is there a list of new laptops without Intel Management Engine built in?

Tags: privacy, remote-desktop, backdoor

Is there a list of new laptops without Intel Management Engine built in?

I'm reading about Intel Management Engine as being a secret backdoor for hackers. (See, https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2017/05/intels-management-engine-security-hazard-and-users-need-way-disable-it).

(I really feel that there are too many "evil clubs" growing side of companies because somebody has leaked a zero day attack against Intel Management Engineer that let's people spy on your while you are working.  Like you are sitting there, and all day there's some evil lazy person drooling over the code you have written so they can steal and get credit for the work without needing to do any real work.  mean while you get tossed out again as a temp contractor.  And the Computer Administrator have no idea this type of thing happens because i ask them.. therefore, its a zero-day on Intel IME engine secretly getting spread around by an "evil club" to hide and steal and dump.)

Personally, I've given up on trying to modify firmware to disable Intel Management Engine.  You need to be a hardware hacker with too much time on your hands to break it according to what i'm reading.

So My approach is this.  Find a laptop that doesn't use the Intel Management Interface Chip.  Does anybody know of a computer or laptop without Intel Management Engine built into the motherboard?

Comment: You know... that Intel ME... is integrated into the main CPU silicon, right?